# Error in VSCode while compiling for the first time in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I got this error when I try to compile my Hello world in C :

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\kuro6\Desktop\programme simple\Cours\C\gcc" does not exist.

I have the C/C++ extension in VSCode with C/C++ compile run and MinGW is correctly installed on my PC (Codeblock work for exemple)

Comment: I don't think you have `gcc` installed in your project folder, read the VSC doc pages about C/C++ and mingw

Comment: get in the habit of NOT using spaces in file/directory names

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, it could be that VSCode is not able to find GCC and also there is a space in your path, so that sometimes causes issues too.

You need to provide more information, as in how the files are organized in your project, what build system you are using, how are you compiling it (Like what command or button are you using). But anyway I'm gonna give you a general-ish solution that works for me.

#### Check for GCC

Go to the terminal and type `gcc --version` into it.

If you get something like this:

```bash
gcc (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It means GCC is installed and should be found by VSCode.

If it's not, just search for "VSCode C C++" or something and it will lead you to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64-on-windows) page that shows you the exact setup under the heading "Example: Install MinGW-x64 on Windows".

#### Building

If you have just one main.c, then you can just pass it straight to GCC and it will compile no questions asked.

```bash
gcc ./main.c -o main.exe
```

If you want to debug it then also tell GCC to add a debug symbols using `-g` or `-g3` and if you want to set the optimization level then pass one of these `-O0`, `-O1`, or `-O3`.

#### Using CMake

If you have lots of files than you can use CMake to manage the builds and pass on stuff to GCC automatically. A simple CMakeLists.txt would be something like this.

```bash
# Tell CMake about your project name and version etc
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
set(PROJECT_NAME "your_project")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Add your executable and attach it to main.c
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

# Add your library folders
add_subdirectory(library_1)
add_subdirectory(library_2)
add_subdirectory(library_3)
add_subdirectory(library_4)
```

But keep in mind that each library folder would also have a CMakeLists.txt. Personally I like to make a folder with the library name, make a .c and .h file with the same name. Like this

```bash
library_1
  |- library_1.h
  |- library_1.c
  |- CMakeLists.txt
```

And then put this in the `library_1` cmake.

```bash
get_filename_component(CURRENT_DIR_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CURRENT_DIR_NAME}.c)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE .)
```

It automatically picks up the library name and the .c and .h file names, so you can just copy paste this in all your libraries.

And then you can build like this

```bash
cmake -GNinja -Bbuild
ninja -C build
```

#### VSCode Extension

I am working on a VSCode extension that does all of these steps for you, and creates a pre-configured CMake project. It also provides buttons for cleaning, building, running, debugging and testing those projects so you don't have to deal with the terminal again and again.

I'm calling it [C Toolkit](https://github.com/usmanmehmood55/c-toolkit).

So as the name suggests it only creates pre-configured projects in C, not C++. But you can create projects and rename the files and it would probably work I think. Lemme know if you decide to use it and if it solves your problem.