# How do I solve this error in VS Code : launch:program 'enter program name, for example c:\c_Programs\a.exe' does not exist

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

strong textI downloaded VS Code a while ago and made a simple "hello world" program. I downloaded the C/C++ extension and when i click f5 and run it with the debugger "C++(GDB/LLDB)" I get this error:

**launch:program 'enter program name, for example c:\c_Programs\a.exe' does not exist.**

I've looked everywhere on the internet but I can't find the answer anywhere. Can someone help me.

Note: im a beginner at C programming so I don't know very much.

Comment: If you haven't rebooted since the install I would suggest that.  For me and something as large as VS, it seems to resolve a few things.   Then, start a brand new project and work with that.  If this doesn't help please say so in these comments, and the community can continue to help you from another approach.   Also -- possibly same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872250/cant-compile-code-launch-program-program-path-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

The debugger can't find your compiled program.

If you haven't compiled it then use GCC to compile it like this

```bash
gcc main.c -o main.exe
```

It will compile your program and make an executable as `main.exe`

Then modify the `launch.json` file in your `.vscode` folder and
reference this `main.exe` in it instead of `a.exe`.

If you want to see more detailed explanations on how to build view my answers here.

[Error in VSCode while compiling for the first time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111239/error-in-vscode-while-compiling-for-the-first-time-in-c/77112180#77112180)

[How to configure so that you don't have to type the entire path to headers in c in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77223215/how-to-configure-so-that-you-dont-have-to-type-the-entire-path-to-headers-in-c/77236731#77236731)