# How to build C/Cpp project using VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have created C project with multiple sub-folders containing .c and .h files.
I've created one file as my main file with main function entry.

I've setup my environment by following this details and I'm able to build and execute single .c file. But I'd like to build my multiple .c in sub-folders.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

**I'm trying to build master/main .c file by using given task.**

And when i try to execute task labelled  `"label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"`

When I execute the same task by opening/keeping any .C file as active opened file, then it tries to build currently opened file.

**Below is the build error**

`**Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file  Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file.**`

I've created below json files

**tasks.json**

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**Thisis my code structure:**

[image]

I'm trying to compile using tasks, it gives error. And i'm not able to link other .h files.

Could anyone guide me on how to link other .h files and sub-folders directories.

Comment: What errors do you get? Please add the complete and exact error messages together with the command line used for compilation, to the question. Copy&paste as formatted text into the question. What file is open in editor when you try to build? Also, what do you mean by "link other .h files"? You never link with header files. You include header files. You link compiled C source files with other compiled files or libraries.

Comment: I've created function in each Assignment folders, included extern their prototypes in Inc.h file and calling each function in my main C_programming.cpp file


`#include "Inc.h"


int main()
{

    printf("My Function entrypoint ..\n");
    
    Assignment_1();
    //Assignment_2();
}`

Comment: yes, I'm trying to find how to link header files in VS code. In case of VS IDE, i use to include lib or other folders in include section. I'm not aware of how to include header in VS code.

Comment: Start with the basics. You have to tell vscode where to find your include files. This is called the *Include Search Path*, in your `c_cpp_properties.json` that is `"includePath"` which currently only searchers `"${workspaceRoot}"` and will not find headers in each of your `Assignment_X` subdirectories. `"includePath"` will need to include each directory you want it to look in (system headers in normal install locations are always included by default) You layout looks like you actually have separate projects under your `Assignment_X` subdirectories, which you can address that way as well.

Comment: Again: Headers are not linked. What is your error message? Is it from compiler or from VSC Editor? What is the command line used for building?

Comment: David, Thank you for your detail. I'll try add this includePath.

Comment: Gerhard, Thank you for your answer. I'm getting undefined function build error.

`
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\cchvtaRR.o: in function `main':
C:/Work/Process/Learning/C_Programming.cpp:9: undefined reference to Assignment_1()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`
`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a project with 4 libraries, for
performing the 4 basic math functions.

```
project
 |
 |- adder
 |   |
 |   |- adder.h
 |   |- adder.c
 |
 |- subtractor
 |   |
 |   |- subtractor.h
 |   |- subtractor.c
 |
 |- multiplier
 |   |
 |   |- multiplier.h
 |   |- multiplier.c
 |
 |- divider
 |   |
 |   |- divider.h
 |   |- divider.c
 |
 |- main.c
```

To compile this, the GCC command would be:

```bash
gcc main.c                                \
-I ./adder      ./adder/adder.c           \
-I ./subtractor ./subtractor/subtractor.c \
-I ./multiplier ./multiplier/multiplier.c \
-I ./divider    ./divider/divider.c       \
-o program
```

Do note that the `\` character is used to split the larger single-line command
into a smaller one, for you to view easily. The actual command would be:

```bash
gcc main.c -I ./adder ./adder/adder.c -I ./subtractor ./subtractor/subtractor.c -I ./multiplier ./multiplier/multiplier.c -I ./divider ./divider/divider.c -o program
```

You can also add optimization flags like `-O0` or `-O2` and debug flags like `-g` or `-g3` at the end.

But whenever making an application (especially in C/C++) with multiple folders and source files, it's much much easier and convenient to use a build system like Make or CMake.

I've explained this process in a little more detail in these answers

- [How to configure so that you don't have to type the entire path to headers in c in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77223215/how-to-configure-so-that-you-dont-have-to-type-the-entire-path-to-headers-in-c/77236731#77236731)
- [Error in VSCode while compiling for the first time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111239/error-in-vscode-while-compiling-for-the-first-time-in-c/77112180#77112180)

Comment: Thank you Usman for your valuable info. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're welcome. And also give my [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) a try. It makes it super easy for you to create CMake projects and libraries along with a bunch of other useful stuff. My own frustrations in making C projects led me to make this extension :D