# includePath settings on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to code c/c++ in vscode but I'm getting this error:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/berat/projects/helloworld/g.c).

c_cpp_properties like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                ""
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

I was trying to solve the `includePath` problem but I didn't.

Comment: It *looks* like your includePath is empty ("").  Maybe you are supposed to puts something there , ie "includePath": [    "c:/dir/include"      ],

Comment: ... why would you put an empty string in there? also, there's no way we can help you if you don't even show your `#include` directive and enough info about your project layout to know where your source file and header file are.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems *compiling* the program or are you having problems configuring the IntelliSense in VSCode?

If you are able to compile and run it, then it is just an IntelliSense problem. In that case you need to modify the `c_cpp_properties.json` to point to the correct paths. You can right click on the header file and select the copy path option, and put that path in the `includePath` array. You can also let it search all files in the project folder using a wildcard.

```json
"includePath" : [ "${workspaceFolder}/**" ],
```

If you are having issues in compilation then you can view my answers here:

- [how to add mingw compiler in vs code to run c prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431785/how-to-add-mingw-compiler-in-vs-code-to-run-c-prog/77436471#77436471)
- [How to build C/Cpp project using VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317329/how-to-build-c-cpp-project-using-vs-code/77330269#77330269)