# Basic C program freezes mid compile in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run this very simple C program in Visual Studio Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

It runs perfectly the first time, though for some reason the output also has some other text:

(`"Hello World!=thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"`)

All times after that, it reaches the point where it's in the terminal at the file directory, then seems to halt without erroring or failing.
Only relaunching VSC solves it, at which point you can run the code one more time before it breaks.

Things I've done so far to set up for running C:

- Installed C++/C extension from microsoft on VSC
- Installed the GNU C++ Compiler & The Basic MinGW Installation on my pc using the MinGW manager
- Installed the Code Runner extension on VSC and enabled "Run code from terminal" in the settings

Am I missing something?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: remove Code Runner and try the launch config method, read the VSC C++ doc

Comment: @J K Write puts("Hello World!"); instead of printf("Hello World!");.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77431785/how-to-add-mingw-compiler-in-vs-code-to-run-c-prog/77436471#77436471), it explains in detail how to compile, run and debug C on vscode.

Comment: If you want to see how to build and run with multiple libraries in multiple files and folders, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317329/how-to-build-c-cpp-project-using-vs-code/77330269#77330269)

Comment: Also check out my [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) that automates all these steps and helps you create C projects with ease.