# VS Codespace issue - cannot run files after opened them

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50, vscode-remote, codespaces

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtQJw.png)

Hello World i am a beginner to learn code and am taking CS50 lesson. today i face a problem on VS codespace. As shown on the picture:

All filenames on the left suddenly changes from white color to green color and there is a blue C symbol before the bottom two files. Originally, there is no C symbol.

For the terminal window, it shows a "route" before the $ sign, which is so inconvenient when use command line. originally there is just showing $ sign.

And after I "cd"(enter) the finished program, I could not run them anymore as shown on picture.

I try to search if anyone faced the same issue but not very the same i found.

I also try to rebuild the codespace but the issue still exists.

Could anyone give me a hand about what is happening and if there is any potential solutions for "reset" it to original state...

thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please don't share images of code/errors.  Please share code and errors as text.  There are many good reasons for this... one is that we often like to compile your code and see if we can duplicate the error, then fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The "blue C symbol" is just VSCode recognizing that these are `.c` files and applying the appropriate icon to them. Nothing to worry about there.
- The folder/file names changing from white to green color are in indication of Git usage. When a file is "staged" or "added", VSCode changes its name's color from white to green. It is a Git related thing, so again, nothing to do with compilation or running, and nothing to worry about.
- If by "route before the $ sign" you mean this thing: `/workspaces/149502043/bulbs (main) $`, then this is also a Git related thing. Again, nothing to worry about.
- The picture you've shown does not show which files are in the `bulbs` folder and what the build process etc is in there, so there's no way of telling what the `./bulbs` command is supposed to do in the terminal.

As indicated in one of the comments, please share code and errors as text, and also please share more details like directory and file structure so that people here can have an idea of what is actually going on.

- Also, see my answer here on how to correctly compile and run C files and projects: [How to build C/Cpp project using VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317329/how-to-build-c-cpp-project-using-vs-code/77330269?noredirect=1#comment136353145_77330269)
- And if you are still having issues creating, building and running C projects, give my VSCode extension a try: [C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit).

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I had solved the problems by simply delete the whole codespace and rebuild and login. still good to learn the knowledge from you tho:)