# Why am I getting undefined symbols in Visual studio code for mac?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use vs code for a project I am doing but it appears to be a headache. In xcode I have no issues running this program but VScode is giving me undefined symbols. I understand that the issue is that it is not linking the .c file but not sure what to do about it.

error:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _StackDestroy, referenced from:
      _main in main-803f4a.o
  _StackInitDefault, referenced from:
      _main in main-803f4a.o
  _StackPush, referenced from:
      _main in main-803f4a.o
  _StackTop, referenced from:
      _main in main-803f4a.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    STACK hStack;
    char c;

    hStack = StackInitDefault();
    if (hStack == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate space for stack object.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    scanf("%c", &c);
    StackPush(hStack, c);

    printf("Top of stack is: %c\n", StackTop(hStack, NULL)); 
    StackDestroy(&hStack);
    return 0;
}
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef stack_h
#define stack_h
#include "status.h"

typedef void* STACK;

STACK StackInitDefault(void);

Status StackPush(STACK hStack, char c);

Status StackPop(STACK hStack);

char StackTop(STACK hStack, Status* pStatus);

void StackDestroy(STACK* phStack);

Boolean StackIsEmpty(STACK hStack);


#endif
```

stack.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "stack.h"

struct node;
typedef struct node Node;

struct node {
    char value;
    Node* next;
};

struct stack {
    Node* head;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

STACK StackInitDefault(void) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    
    if (pStack != NULL) {  
        pStack->head = NULL;
    }
    
    return pStack;
}
    
Boolean StackIsEmpty(STACK hStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    
    return (pStack->head == NULL)?TRUE:FALSE;
}

char StackTop(STACK hStack, Status* pStatus) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    
    if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
        if (pStatus != NULL) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        return 'e';
    }
    if (pStatus != NULL) {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    return pStack->head->value;
}


Status StackPush(STACK hStack, char c) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    
    temp->value = c;
    temp->next = pStack->head;
    pStack->head = temp;
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

Status StackPop(STACK hStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)hStack;
    Node* temp;
    
    if (StackIsEmpty(hStack)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    
    temp = pStack->head;
    pStack->head = pStack->head->next;
    free(temp);
    
    return SUCCESS;
}

void StackDestroy(STACK* phStack) {
    Stack* pStack = (Stack*)*phStack;
    Node* temp = pStack->head;
    
    while (pStack->head != NULL) {
        temp = pStack->head;
        pStack->head = pStack->head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(pStack);
    
    *phStack = NULL;
}
```

status.h

```
#ifndef status_h
#define status_h

enum status { FAILURE, SUCCESS };
typedef enum status Status;

enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };
typedef enum boolean Boolean;

#endif
```

Comment: you need to LINK  stack.o too

Comment: I see. Would you mind telling me how I would go about doing that?

Comment: What are you doing for compiling and linking? Which tutorial are you following? What does the tutorial say about multiple .c source files in a project?

Comment: I am not following a tutorial so I am unsure. I just want to simply try out vs code. I am a second semester cs student and have only used xcode. My professor has told me that next semester we will be learning more about how to work with terminal and such. Sorry if my questions seem a bit dumb I just do not know much about about linking or compiling outside of just clicking the run button on xcode.

Comment: VSCode is a very nice tool, but configuring it the first time is like a game of chance: either you are lucky and it works fine out of the box or you are not and it will be a pain in the ass to just make it work. My advice: use a tutorial for the first config and only add your own sources after that first step.

Answer (score -1):

#### Note

This answer is mostly copied from my answer to [How to build C/Cpp project using VS code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317329/how-to-build-c-cpp-project-using-vs-code/77330269), I'm writing it here again for your ease of reading.

#### Answer

Here's a C project with 4 libraries, for
performing the 4 basic math functions.

```
project
 |
 |- adder
 |   |
 |   |- adder.h
 |   |- adder.c
 |
 |- subtractor
 |   |
 |   |- subtractor.h
 |   |- subtractor.c
 |
 |- multiplier
 |   |
 |   |- multiplier.h
 |   |- multiplier.c
 |
 |- divider
 |   |
 |   |- divider.h
 |   |- divider.c
 |
 |- main.c
```

To compile this, the GCC command would be:

```bash
gcc main.c                                \
-I ./adder      ./adder/adder.c           \
-I ./subtractor ./subtractor/subtractor.c \
-I ./multiplier ./multiplier/multiplier.c \
-I ./divider    ./divider/divider.c       \
-o program
```

Do note that the `\` character is used to split the larger single-line command
into a smaller one, for you to view easily. The actual command would be:

```bash
gcc main.c -I ./adder ./adder/adder.c -I ./subtractor ./subtractor/subtractor.c -I ./multiplier ./multiplier/multiplier.c -I ./divider ./divider/divider.c -o program
```

You can also add optimization flags like `-O0` or `-O2` and debug flags like `-g` or `-g3` at the end.

But whenever making an application (especially in C/C++) with multiple folders and source files, it's much much easier and convenient to use a build system like Make or CMake.

I've explained this process in a little more detail in these answers

- [How to configure so that you don't have to type the entire path to headers in c in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77223215/how-to-configure-so-that-you-dont-have-to-type-the-entire-path-to-headers-in-c/77236731#77236731)
- [Error in VSCode while compiling for the first time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111239/error-in-vscode-while-compiling-for-the-first-time-in-c/77112180#77112180)

And also give my [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) a try. It makes it super easy for you to create CMake projects and libraries along with a bunch of other useful stuff. My own frustrations in making C projects led me to make this extension :D